# Tracking file downloads

Tags: php, symfony, download

I want to make an area in symfony2 where I have the list of files which users can download.

I want to be able to track how many times each file has been downloaded.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can achieve that?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code please

Comment: I am going to start today so just wanted to know if anyone can give some directions to start with

Comment: Ok. As you want to track the number of downloads you can't just link to your file directly. You need a controller who serves the file and keeps track of the number of clicks.

An similar example can be found here: http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/2009/08/03/serving-pdf-files-through-symfony-controllers/

This should give you a start.

Comment: @kufi please remove the example, it's for older version of Symfony, which is completely different and irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple way in your list of files you must set URL to your controller, which will count the number of downloads and than print direct link to file.

```
{# list of files in template %}
{% for file in files %}
    <a href="{% path('counting', {'id': file.id}) %}">{{ file.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}

// Controller
/**
 * Counting the number of file downloads
 *
 * @Route("/counting/{id}", name="counting", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function countingAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $file = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:File')->find($id);

    $count = $file->getCount();
    $file->setCount($count + 1);

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    return array('file' => $file);
}

{# final file page in template #}
<a href="{{ file.url }}">{{ file.name }}</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Doctrine Entity – some infos are in this article "[How to handle file upload](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)"

Comment: "I want to make an area in symfony2 where i have the list of files which users can **download**."